# PostgreSQL - Inserindo dados em tabelas ligadas por Foreign Key

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Olá!

Estou com um problema de inserção de dados em tabelas ligadas por chave estrangeira. Li em alguns lugares que existe um comando "with" que ajuda nessa situações, mas não entendi direito como se usa.

Gostaria de juntar quatro tabelas que serão utilizadas para efetuar um cadastro, porém, que todos os dados fossem inseridos de vez, em apenas uma query, e que ficassem associados com a última tabela, para facilitar futuras consultas. Abaixo segue o código de criação das tabelas:

```
    CREATE TABLE participante
        (
          id serial NOT NULL,
          nome character varying(56) NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT participante_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
        );

    CREATE TABLE venda
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      inicio date NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT venda_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE item
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      nome character varying(256) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT item_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );


    CREATE TABLE lances_vendas
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      venda_id integer NOT NULL,
      item_id integer NOT NULL,
      participante_id integer NOT NULL,
      valor numeric NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT lance_vendas_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT lances_vendas_venda_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (venda_id)
        REFERENCES venda (id),
      CONSTRAINT lances_vendas_item_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES item (id),
      CONSTRAINT lances_vendas_participante_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (participante_id)
        REFERENCES participante (id)
    );
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda e a compreensão de vocês.

Comment: Fiz as consultas separadas de cada tabela (menos da última), seguem abaixo: `INSERT INTO item (nome) values (?);` `INSERT INTO venda (inicio) values (?);` `INSERT INTO participante (nome) values (?);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
WITH    
   venda AS (insert into venda(inicio) values (now()) returning id), 
   item as (insert into item(nome) values ('batata-frita') returning id), 
   participante as(insert into participante(nome) values ('Anselmo') returning id)

     insert into lances_vendas(venda_id, item_id, participante_id, valor) 
        select *, 100 from venda, item, participante;
```